# VBA script convert folder of .rtf files to .docx files - two minor problems

Tags: vba, ms-word

I use a VBA script (see below) in Word 2013 to convert a folder of .rtf files to .docx files. It mostly works, but has two minor problems.

1. I have to acknowledge that each original file is an .rtf file. When Word opens each .rtf file there's a dialog that requires me to confirm that each file is an .rtf file.
2. When I view converted .docx files in Word there's a "compatibility mode" header, which suggests that I haven't properly converted.

Are there any fixes for these problems? The first one kind of undermines the whole point of scripting and I'm afraid the second one will cause unforeseen problems.

```
Sub ConvertRtfToDocx()

    Set oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select folder..."
        .Show
        myFolder = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    myWildCard = InputBox(prompt:="Enter wild card...")

    myDocs = Dir(myFolder & "\" & myWildCard)

    While myDocs <> ""
        Debug.Print myDocs
        Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(myFolder & "\" & myDocs)
        oDoc.SaveAs myFolder & "\" & Left(myDocs, Len(myDocs) - 4) & ".docx", _
            wdFormatXMLDocument
        myDocs = Dir()
    Wend
    oWord.Quit

End Sub
```

Comment: which application you run this code from? which version of Office you use? I tested it for 2010 and there aren't any problems as you mentioned...

Comment: @KazJaw I use Word 2013. Could it matter that the .rtf files are made by some Java-based program?

Comment: I don't think it is because the .rtf files are not made in Word. I made a simple .rtf file in Word and had the same two problems.

Comment: So, I can't reproduce the error you have therefore I have simple suggestion for you regarding point 1- try to add `Application.DisplayAllerts = False` at the beginning and set it back to `True` in the end. Or try this way `oWord.DisplayAllerts = False` and so on...

Comment: @KazJaw Neither work. Both symptoms persist.

Comment: @KazJaw I have solutions. My guess is that you couldn't recreate my errors because you've wisely changed the Word defaults. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code works.

```
Sub ConvertRtfToDocx()

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = "Select folder..."
        .Show
        myFolder = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With

    myWildCard = InputBox(prompt:="Enter wild card...")

    myDocs = Dir(myFolder & "\" & myWildCard)

    While myDocs <> ""
        Documents.Open FileName:=myFolder & "\" & myDocs, ConfirmConversions:=False
        ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:=myFolder & "\" & Left(myDocs, Len(myDocs) - 4) & ".docx", _
            FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault, _
            CompatibilityMode:=wdCurrent
        ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=False
        myDocs = Dir()
    Wend

End Sub
```

I did some restructuring (e.g., use `ActiveDocument` instead of creating my own object), but the real changes that did it were to

1. set `ConfirmConversions:=False` on open
2. use the `SaveAs2` method and set `FileFormat:=wdFormatDocumentDefault` and `CompatibilityMode:=wdCurrent`

I guess that both of these can be set as default (I'm overwhelmed by Office options and leave the defaults).

Comment: Why this is not marked as answer?

Comment: I don’t remember. It was ten years ago. :)